# Focus from iframes is blurred only after 2-3 taps on other elements in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iframe, mobile-safari

I have recreated a small example of a button with three iframes. When you scroll through the page and just tap on any iframe (just to make a hovering effect), the focus is set on that iframe, which is fine. But, when any other element is tapped (`button` in this case), the focus from the iframe doesn't get blurred instantly. One has to tap the button atleast 2-3 times to set the focus on the button. How can this be fixed?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

<style type="text/css">
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.container {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#click_check, button {
    margin: 12px 0px;
}
iframe {
    display: block;
    height: 240px;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    border: 0px;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div id="click_check">clicked 0 times</div>
    <button>Click Me</button>
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/f_2rM8A_1-w"></iframe>
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_I6I2JOJhHY"></iframe>
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RntZL4VpVus"></iframe>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
let count = 0;
let output = document.getElementById('click_check');
let button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

function click() {
    count ++;
    output.innerHTML = 'clicked ' + count + ' times';
}

button.addEventListener('click', click);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to know, I fixed it with

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => { e.preventDefault(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

when I used tab navigation and passed iframe while I pressed the tab key. Then when I tab to one of the buttons and trigger a click/keydown event, it won't work the first time, it seems like it's looking for the iframe.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34757219)